# Retrieve and display YouTube video description, title by its id using YouTube API

Tags: php, json, youtube-api

I would like to display on a page the title and description of a video youtube, I know how do this for count number with this php code

```
<?php
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?
part=statistics&id=videoID&key=APIKey");
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);
echo $json_data['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
?>
```

But i don't know how do this do display video title and description.

Comment: can you add `$JSON`??

Comment: Sorry what do you mean ?

Comment: add the value of `$JSON`

Comment: Sorry perhaps this can help : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$JSON = file_get_contents("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?
part=snippet&id=videoID&key=APIKey");
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);
echo $json_data['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
echo $json_data['items'][0]['snippet']['description'];
?>
```