# YouTube API - Pulling back the title, description and the release date

Tags: php, youtube, youtube-api

I've looked on around and can't seem to see anything helping me out. If there are any posts please point me towards them.

Anyway... I wish to pull back the titles, description and release dates of the videos so they can be displayed on the webpage.

```
<div class="ytback">
        <div class="ytframe">   
          <div class="ytvid">
            <iframe width="560" height="315" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $video->snippet->resourceId->videoId . '?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
          </div>
            <div class="ytdesc">
                <h2>' . $video->title . '</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Dicta, pariatur, accusamus, distinctio debitis fugit accusantium ab nulla optio blanditiis dolor fuga aspernatur omnis quasi voluptatum natus delectus ipsa nam provident!</p>
                <div class="ytdate">
                    <p style="font-style:italic; font-size:10px;">date released: 01/01/2016</p>
                </div>  
            </div>
          </div>
       </div>
          ';
        endforeach
```

Just wondered how i would display the title, description and the release date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retreive and display YouTube video description, title by its id using YouTube API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022332/retreive-and-display-youtube-video-description-title-by-its-id-using-youtube-ap)

Comment: Try to check this [page](https://webtoolsplus.com/get-youtube-title-and-description-from-php/) if it can help you :)