# Cannot get video title from YouTube video object

Tags: php, magento, video, youtube

This question is not a duplicate. My problem is not displaying wrong part of data, as it is at the marked article, but as an attentive user reflected, "The concrete problem in your question is that you use a URL that retrieves the actual video only, not the page containing the video."

I'd need to get the title of a YouTube video for a Magento webshop. My code is the following right now:

```html
$videocode = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);
$url =  "http://www.youtube.com/v/".$videocode."?hl=en_US&amp;version=3";
echo $url;
$videoTitle = file_get_contents($url);
try {
    if ($videoTitle) {
       preg_match("/<title>(.+?)<\/title>/is", $videoTitle, $titleOfVideo);
       echo $titleOfVideo[1];
    } else {
       return false;
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
}
```

The `echo $url;` returns the correct video url.

But afterwards, if I try to var_dump the $videoTitle, it returns something like `CWS[%xڍZ[{�Fzƀ�@�:Ҷ��v"�uh �H�(E�9����ή�   $1=�馧m�=nϽko�z������$��M��_l�oR�lﳶ�����~�� �C)��4��4ʤ[SI�nM�"�.��b�yB��ᵵ��5�u�8�\�`, I mean a bunch of them. 
But it doesn't return false.

For the $titleOfVideo it returns `array(0) { }`.
Otherwise if I don't try to echo or var_dump anything, it doesn't give back anything for me.
What am I missing here?

---

After being directed and making some research, my code looks the following:

```html
$videocode = $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']);
$videocode = explode('&feature=youtu.be', $videocode);
$url =  "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id‌​=".$videocode[0]."&key=".$apikey;
echo $url;
$json = file_get_contents($url);
var_dump($json); //bool(false)
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
if ($json_data) {
   print_r($json_data);
} else {
   return false;
}
```

The video ID is correct. But my `$json` return `false`. What am I missing still?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Retrieve and display YouTube video description, title by its id using YouTube API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022332/retrieve-and-display-youtube-video-description-title-by-its-id-using-youtube-ap)

Comment: Use the official API instead of trying to read meta data from the live site. The concrete problem in your question is that you use a URL that retrieves the actual video only, not the page containing the video.

Comment: @NineBerry, after looking a bit after the way YouTube API work, I've concluded, that if the `$videocode` is the only detail I've got regarding the video, then it's not enough to perform the desired action. Am I right?

Comment: It's enough. See the code in the linked question. However, you also need your own apikey which you will receive by registering with Google to use the Youtube API. See https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started on how to get an API key

Comment: @NineBerry I've got my API key now. I'm just wondering the how does my request URL has to look like. Is it somehow like `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=".$videocode."&key=APIKey`? My $videocode looks like for ex. `dRvS-tLCi5Y&feature=youtu.be`.

Comment: The URL must look like this: `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=dRvS-tLCi5Y&key=APIKey` You must remove the part after the actual code in your `$videocode` variable and you must include the `part=Snippet`

Comment: @NineBerry so now my code looks like ` $videocode = explode('&feature=youtu.be', $videocode);
                    $url =  "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id‌​=".$videocode[0]."&key=".$apikey;
                    $json = file_get_contents($url);
                    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
                    if ($json_data) {
                        print_r($json_data);
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }`. But I still dont get back anything.

Comment: If I just simply navigate to the url, then I get a `"code": 400,
  "message": "No filter selected. Expected one of: id, myRated, chart"`. But there is a correct filter.

Comment: if I do a var_dump($json) it returns bool(false).

Comment: This is a problem of copying the code from the stackoverflow comment. There are invisible special characters in the code. Just type the URL manually into your code editor instead of copying from here. Or I'll write an answer, where you can copy the code from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Google API to access meta data of Youtube videos.

First you have to register with Google to receive an API Key. Follow [these instructions](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started) to do so.

Then you can construct an URL to retrieve the Title like this:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=dRvS-tLCi5Y&key=YourAPIKey
```

Use your API Key in place.

This will return the following JSON:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/nmxGC9Qyfl2o0ayvTd9DwRpHySo\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/WzAkhb8NRCtBYcATr8BHzcJJ8sE\"",
   "id": "dRvS-tLCi5Y",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2015-11-17T20:49:02.000Z",
    "channelId": "UCuTn1q6pg2kKRLAQIWSEO5g",
    "title": "Womanizer - W500 Pro Klitoris Stimulator NYHED",
    "description": "Womanizers unikke teknologi stimulerer din klitoris på en helt unik måde. Teknologien blander en sugende og pustende fornemmelse på klitoris og evt brystvorter, der sørger for \"orgasme garanti\". Stimulatoren har 8 unikke indstilinger, der giver dig en fantastisk oplevelse. Stimulatoren er formet, så den ligger godt i hånden. Mundstykket kan udskiftes og rengøres. Genopladelig med medfølgende USB kabel.\n\nGod fornøjelse :)\n\nKøb i dag hos: http://www.winkwink.dk/womanizer-w500-pro-klitoris-stimulator-nyhed.html",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dRvS-tLCi5Y/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dRvS-tLCi5Y/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dRvS-tLCi5Y/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dRvS-tLCi5Y/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/dRvS-tLCi5Y/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "Winkwink.dk",
    "tags": [
     "#sexlegetøj",
     "#winkwinkdk",
     "#sex",
     "#winkwink",
     "#womanizer",
     "#julegave",
     "#lovewinkwinkdk",
     "#stimulator",
     "#klitoris",
     "Clitoris (Anatomical Structure)"
    ],
    "categoryId": "22",
    "liveBroadcastContent": "none",
    "localized": {
     "title": "Womanizer - W500 Pro Klitoris Stimulator NYHED",
     "description": "Womanizers unikke teknologi stimulerer din klitoris på en helt unik måde. Teknologien blander en sugende og pustende fornemmelse på klitoris og evt brystvorter, der sørger for \"orgasme garanti\". Stimulatoren har 8 unikke indstilinger, der giver dig en fantastisk oplevelse. Stimulatoren er formet, så den ligger godt i hånden. Mundstykket kan udskiftes og rengøres. Genopladelig med medfølgende USB kabel.\n\nGod fornøjelse :)\n\nKøb i dag hos: http://www.winkwink.dk/womanizer-w500-pro-klitoris-stimulator-nyhed.html"
    },
    "defaultAudioLanguage": "da"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can then read the title like this:

```
$json_data = json_decode($JSON, true);
$title = $json_data['items'][0]['snippet']['title'];
```

---

Note that using the Youtube API is preferred because any attempt to use the live site to read meta data of videos will result in youtube identifying these requests and blocking calls (showing a Captcha instead of delivering the real video code)

Comment: It's interesting. It prints the url correctly, but after copying the two url's to compare, mine, that is returned from the script, has an additional `%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B` before the after the `&id` and before the actual ID...

Comment: As I said, that is because you copied it from the comment here. The special characters are inserted where there is a line break in a comment on Stack Overflow

Comment: Nope, it's from the page itself, returned by `echo $url;`. Maybe the `$videocode[0]` is not the best solution over here...

Comment: They come because you copied part of the url from my previous comment into your code editor. Just remove the special characters there. You can't see them. It's invisible spaces between the id and the =. You can't see them, but you will see they are there by stepping through the text with cursor keys.

Comment: You can see why this happens in this discussion on stackexchange meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170970/occasionally-the-unicode-character-sequence-u200c-u200b-zwnj-zwsp-is-insert

Comment: Man, thanks for your patience, I've misunderstood you before. It works, and I've learnt a lot from you! Thank you and good luck! :)